# Jasmine Spy not Returning Correct Value

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spy

In my Jasmine test specs, on occasion I spy on `authState`, a property of my mock service `mockAngularFireAuth` and return different values representative of the state of the app under that specific test.

In one test this works perfectly and the assertion is correct; see the test:

```
AuthService
  catastrophically fails
```

However, when I spy on `authState` in exactly the same way in the test (for example)…

```
AuthService
  can’t authenticate anonymously
    AuthService.currentUid
      should return undefined
```

…the assertion `expect(service.currentUid).toBeUndefined()` fails.

The `currentUid` remains as it was set initially, a string ("17WvU2Vj58SnTz8v7EqyYYb0WRc2").

Here is a trimmed down version of my test specs (this includes only the test specs in question):

```
import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { MockUser} from './mock-user';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

// An anonymous user
const authState: MockUser = {
  displayName: null,
  isAnonymous: true,
  uid: '17WvU2Vj58SnTz8v7EqyYYb0WRc2'
};

// Mock AngularFireAuth
const mockAngularFireAuth: any = {
  auth: jasmine.createSpyObj('auth', {
    'signInAnonymously': Promise.resolve(authState)
  }),
  authState: Observable.of(authState)
};

describe('AuthService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: mockAngularFireAuth },
        { provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthService }
      ]
    });
  });

  …

  describe('can’t authenticate anonymously', () => {

    …

    describe('AuthService.currentUid', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        // const spy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(mockAngularFireAuth, 'authState');
        //
        // spy.and.returnValue(Observable.of(null));
        //
        mockAngularFireAuth.authState = Observable.of(null);
      });

      it('should return undefined',
        inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
          expect(service.currentUid).toBeUndefined();
        }));
    });
  });

  describe('catastrophically fails', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      const spy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(mockAngularFireAuth, 'authState');

      spy.and.returnValue(Observable.throw(new Error('Some catastrophe')));
    });

    describe('AngularFireAuth.authState', () => {
      it('should invoke it’s onError function', () => {
        mockAngularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(null,
          (error: Error) => {
            expect(error).toEqual(new Error('Some catastrophe'));
          });
      });
    });

    describe('AuthService.currentUid', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        mockAngularFireAuth.authState = Observable.of(null);
      });

      it('should return undefined',
        inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
          expect(service.currentUid).toBeUndefined();
        }));
    });
  });

  describe('is authenticated anonymously already', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // const spy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(mockAngularFireAuth, 'authState');
      //
      // spy.and.returnValue(Observable.of(authState));
      //
      mockAngularFireAuth.authState = Observable.of(authState);
    });

    describe('.authSate.isAnonymous', () => {
      it('should be true', async(() => {
        mockAngularFireAuth.authState.subscribe((data: MockUser) => {
          expect(data.isAnonymous).toBeTruthy();
        });
      }));
    });

    describe('AuthService.currentUid', () => {
      it('should return "17WvU2Vj58SnTz8v7EqyYYb0WRc2"',
        inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
          expect(service.currentUid).toBe('17WvU2Vj58SnTz8v7EqyYYb0WRc2');
        }));
    });
  });

  describe('is authenticated with Facebook already', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      const obj: MockUser = authState;
      // const spy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(mockAngularFireAuth, 'authState');
      //
      // spy.and.returnValue(Observable.of(Object.assign(obj, {
      //   isAnonymous: false,
      //   uid: 'ZzVRkeduEW1bJC6pmcmb9VjyeERt'
      // })));
      //
      mockAngularFireAuth.authState = Observable.of(Object.assign(obj, {
        isAnonymous: false,
        uid: 'ZzVRkeduEW1bJC6pmcmb9VjyeERt'
      }));
    });

    describe('.authSate.isAnonymous', () => {
      it('should be false', () => {
        mockAngularFireAuth.authState.subscribe((data: MockUser) => {
          expect(data.isAnonymous).toBe(false);
        });
      });
    });

    describe('AuthService.currentUid', () => {
      it('should return "ZzVRkeduEW1bJC6pmcmb9VjyeERt"',
        inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
          expect(service.currentUid).toBe('ZzVRkeduEW1bJC6pmcmb9VjyeERt');
        }));
    });
  });
});
```

**You can see where I've commented out the the spies and instead had to highjack the `authSate` property of `mockAngularFireAuth`** to get the assertions to succeed, by forcibly changing it's value — something I shouldn't be doing as `mockAngularFireAuth` is a constant.

For completeness, here is (a partial of) the service under test:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private authState: firebase.User;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { this.init(); }

  private init (): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((authState: firebase.User) => {
      if (authState === null) {
        this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
          .then((authState: firebase.User) => {
            this.authState = authState;
          })
          .catch((error: Error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      } else {
        this.authState = authState;
      }
    }, (error: Error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  public get currentUid(): string {
    return this.authState ? this.authState.uid : undefined;
  }
}
```

Is it because the in the specs with assertions that fail I have not subscribed to `authState` and therefore the spy doesn't return the respective values I've set?

### Update:

I think this may be because Jasmine can't spy on properties (no my knowledge) that are not functions, or getters/setters.

But then why does the spy in

```
AuthService
  catastrophically fails
```

pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my update; you can't spy on properties — only functions (or methods) and property getters and setters.

Instead, I added a `setAuthState` method to `mockAngularFireAuth` that can alter the value if the `authState` property.

It is essentially doing exactly the same as I was, but without breaking the rules of constants in TypeScript. As it's a mock service, I don't think it matters that this additional method exists.

I am not entirely sure why the successful spec is so, however. I think it may be because the method `throw` is as such a function; therefore it could become the return value of a Jasmine spy.

Here is how I changed my test:

```
// Mock AngularFireAuth
const mockAngularFireAuth: any = {
  auth: jasmine.createSpyObj('auth', {
    'signInAnonymously': Promise.resolve(authState)
  }),
  authState: Observable.of(authState),
  setAuthState: (authState: MockUser): void => {
    mockAngularFireAuth.authState = Observable.of(authState);
  }
};
```

Note the `setAuthState`.

And this is how I've changed my specs (a representative example):

```
describe('AuthService.currentUid', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockAngularFireAuth.setAuthState(null);
  });

  it('should return undefined',
    inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
      expect(service.currentUid).toBeUndefined();
    }));
});
```